Как создать экземпляр типа указанного в дженерике?
class Cat[T]:
    def __init__(self):
      self.prop = T()


Никак, потому что конструктор может требовать какие-то обязательные аргументы, о которых вы не знаете и знать не можете

Несколько вариантов решения. Можно явно передавать в инит функцию, которая будет создавать пустой объект. Либо указать, что T наследуется от какого-то абстрактного объекта/протокола, в котором есть какой-то метод инициализации, в ините дергать этот метод.

@insolor но чтобы дёрнуть конкретный метод конкретного T, этот самый конкретный T нужно как-то получить, но, насколько я понял, надёжного метода получить его не существует

@andreymal, да, похоже на то. Значит через фабрику.

Вариант через передачу фабрики (функции) для значения prop:
from typing import Callable


class Cat[T]:
    prop: T

    def __init__(self, prop_factory: Callable[[], T]) -> None:
        self.prop = prop_factory()


cat = Cat(str)

Дополнительно указывать str в квадратных скобках (типа cat = Cat[str](str)) не нужно (излишне), тайп чекеры и так определят тип T по типу возвращаемого значения переданной фабрики.

И правда. Нужно передавать подобные данные в РАНТАЙМ среде (тогда они будут доступны и в рантайме и в тайп чекинге), передавать подобные штуки в тайп чекинг среде (в квадратных скобках), а потом пытаться их "выковорить" всякими хаками в рантайме, такое себе занятие =)
